# tableView.reloadData() error: Ambiguous reference to member

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, alamofire

I'm trying to reload the data in my table once a successful GET request has been performed. However I was thrown this error when I wrote *self.tableView.reloadData()*:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

This is the affected code

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    let url = "http://api.myawesomeapp.com"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            if let data = json["name"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                self.datas = data
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

[image: tableview reload error]

This is a link to the full code https://codeshare.io/eMqIx

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have an outlet called `tableView`. Create one, connect it to Interface Builder and you should be fine.