# Ambiguous reference to member '(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to `GET` gists from Github and pop them in a table view, 
here's the entire code, `Gist` is a class defined elsewhere:

```
var gists = [Gist]()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loadGists()
}

func loadGists() {
    GithubAPIManager.sharedInstance.fetchPublicGists() { result in
        guard result.error == nil else {
            print("Error 1")
            return
        }

        if let fetchedGists = result.value {
            self.gists = fetchedGists
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        //Error here. 
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return gists.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!

    let gist = gists[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = gist.description
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = gist.ownerLogin

    return cell
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152014/tableview-reloaddata-error-ambiguous-reference-to-member This should help.

Comment: Yeah you are right @AntonTarasov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is I didn't add an outlet of the table view to the View Controller.swift. 
Just dragged the table view to the .swift file to create it.